# How to transpose a sympy matrix

Tags: python, sympy

I have a problem using the sympy library.
I want to transpose a matrix but it does not work. My code is

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')

J = Matrix([[1+x,2+y,3*x],[4*x,5+x,6*y],[7+y,8*y,9+x]])


Jtrans = Transpose(J)

print(J)
print(Jtrans)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the shorthand `J.T`.

```
>>> J
Matrix([
[x + 1, y + 2,   3*x],
[  4*x, x + 5,   6*y],
[y + 7,   8*y, x + 9]])
>>> Transpose(J)
Matrix([
[x + 1, y + 2,   3*x],
[  4*x, x + 5,   6*y],
[y + 7,   8*y, x + 9]])'
>>> #'
>>> J.T
Matrix([
[x + 1,   4*x, y + 7],
[y + 2, x + 5,   8*y],
[  3*x,   6*y, x + 9]])
```

Comment: that did the job, ty

Answer (score 1):

it is working fine for me:

```
Matrix([[x + 1, y + 2, 3*x], [4*x, x + 5, 6*y], [y + 7, 8*y, x + 9]])
Matrix([
[x + 1, y + 2,   3*x],
[  4*x, x + 5,   6*y],
[y + 7,   8*y, x + 9]])'
```

Note the small `'` after the second matrix? That's your transpose operation.

Comment: shouldn't the output be [ x + 1,   4*x, y + 7]
                                     [ y + 2, x + 5,   8*y]
                                     [   3*x,   6*y, x + 9] ?

Comment: The two are mathematically equivalent.